# "tcl.h: no such file or directory error" in compilation of cgnstools

Tags: software-installation

I installed CGNS source code(downloaded from github) to implement it into CFL3D. I used commands(./configure, make, make install).
I have installed tk-dev and tcl-dev packages, the earlier error was "tk.h: no such file or directory" that is resolved after specifying the path(/usr/include/tk/tk.h) in "make.defs" file in the cgnstools directory but now compiler is not finding tcl.h file. Please suggest.

```
----- cgnsview -----
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/magan/CGNS-3.4.0/src/cgnstools/cgnsview'
gcc -g -O2  -I/home/magan/CGNS-3.4.0/src /usr/include/tk/tk.h -c cgiowish.c
/usr/include/tk/tk.h:19:10: fatal error: tcl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <tcl.h>
          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
cgiowish.c:15:10: fatal error: tk.h: No such file or directory
 #include "tk.h"
          ^~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile.unix:115: recipe for target 'cgiowish.o' failed
make[1]: *** [cgiowish.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/magan/CGNS-3.4.0/src/cgnstools/cgnsview'
Makefile:57: recipe for target 'prog-cgnsview' failed
make: *** [prog-cgnsview] Error 2
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include enough information so someone can duplicate the problem (i.e. how you obtained the CGNS source, what sequence of commands you used to configure and compile it)

Answer (score 0):

There is an app from apt family called apt-file. With this app you can search by filenames and it will return the package (or packages) that provides the searched file.
You can install it with `apt-get install apt-file`, then execute `apt-file update`. After that, you can search your file with `apt-file search tcl.h`. For me (Debian 9 here), the results where (the list is long, I cut it here) :

```
...
tcl8.5-dev: /usr/include/tcl8.5/tcl-private/generic/tcl.h
tcl8.5-dev: /usr/include/tcl8.5/tcl.h
tcl8.6-dev: /usr/include/tcl8.6/tcl-private/generic/tcl.h
tcl8.6-dev: /usr/include/tcl8.6/tcl.h
tcllib: /usr/share/doc/tcllib/html/me_tcl.html
...
```

In my system, I would install one of the packages tcl8.5-dev or tcl8.6-dev. Also, may be necessary to indicate where the lib is located. Usually it is done through an option on the ./configure script. Try execute `./configure --help | less` for finding all available options.

Comment: Actually cgnstools' executables were already created in directory '/usr/bin' as source code was installed, but I didn't check, I thought, I would have to install cgnstools from a subdirectory  'cgnstools'.  thanks for replying